# HD web cam that has good Linux support

Tags: linux, drivers, webcam

I'm looking for a HD (720p or up) webcam, that has good Linux support. Good linux support for me is, in the order of preference:

1. Mainline kernel support in 2.6.31 kernel or older.
2. Debian packaged modules, or source that can be compiled with module-assistant.
3. Kernel module source compilable separately for an installed Debian kernel.

Completely open source is best, but binary firmware blobs are acceptable. A required proprietary management daemon for a driver is not acceptable, as are binary-only distributions of kernel modules and/or management daemons.

I'd like the web cam to be one of the following models, but other readily available models are accepted as well:

1. Creative Live! Cam Socialize HD
2. Logitech Portable Webcam C905
3. Logitech QuickCam Pro for Notebooks
4. Logitech Webcam C600 HD
5. Logitech Webcam Pro 9000 for Business
6. Microsoft LifeCam Cinema

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would be good to get something that uses USB Video Class, since that's standardized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the Logitech Orbit A/F.

It use the standard uvc driver, support upto 1600x1200 resolution.

The picture quality is very good for a webcam.

About ~$100, it also comes with auto focus and motorized base.  There are open source discussion on how to drive the motorized base.  I have not tried those program/command.

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for. It seems the same camera is called Logitech Sphere AF in europe and it costs somewhat more.

Comment: BTW, it has audio support too, if you need that.  I have not tried that on Linux neither.